# How does 遥望却间隔 translate to "Look at the distance?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

A lyric from this song: 
https://mojim.com/cny111282x11x2.htm

https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E9%81%A5%E6%9C%9B%E5%8D%B4%E9%97%B4%E9%9A%94

遥望 means to look into the distance?
却 is however?
间隔 is interval or space?

What is the significance of 却 and 间隔？

They seem to have no purpose in this statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The level of lyric writing is generally bad in Hong Kong compare to the golden era of 70's and 80's.

遥望 - look from afar

却 - but

间隔 - divided. - *It should use 相隔 (separated)*

The writer wrote "遥望却间隔"  wanted to express "I (can) watch (her) from a distance but we are divided, (therefore I can't get near her) "

"Look at the distance" is the translation of 遥望 only

遥望却间隔 should be translated as "can only look from afar but we are divided" (which is the original meaning, and the phrasing is quite awkward )

A better phrasing is 可望(而)不可即 (can watch but cannot get close)